# Register user without password in XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I want to implement Registration functionality same as Whatsapp (without password).
I search alot but not getting best solution.

Currently I'm using Device id and password to register user, and its working fine. but if user logged out or want to login from other device then how I can proceed them with new device id?

My current code to get device id and register user :

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
String androidId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.getInstance(xmpptcpConnection);
        try {
            Localpart from = Localpart.from(mobileNumber);
            if (accountManager.supportsAccountCreation()) {
                accountManager.sensitiveOperationOverInsecureConnection(true);
                accountManager.createAccount(mobileNumber, androidId);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
        }
```

Comment: any luck with the 4th point of vitalyster ?

Comment: were you able to connect without password ?

Answer (score 0):

1. What if I enter phone number and device id of my victim to authenticate as him and read his messages? First of all, you need to verify I have access to this phone number with some verification code via sms/call.
2. What if I want to log in to my account with desktop or Apple device? You should not rely on Android device id, and definitely it shouldn't be a password. You can create just random token string when user add a new device (after verification!) and keep all tokens on the server linked to the user phone number.
3. How my app will create an account in this case? You should have a custom application on the server, which receives verification codes and generates password strings.
4. How my app will authenticate? XMPP standards uses pluggable authentication framework ([SASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer)) and you server and client apps should implement some "token-based" SASL mechanism and uses it instead of "password-based".

Comment: yes i m using OTP to authenticate user's mobile. can u please give more detail about your 4th point.